# Check table for empty cells or cells with zero

Tags: python, pyqt

I have project with gui - table, few input fields, output field and buttons. I created a simple code to check if numbers in input fields are positive, and if they are not - stop further calculation and print out error message in output field. How to check table cells for negative numbers or empty?
my logic - Data inputed in fields and table, button pressed and if one of input fields or one of table cells have negative\zero\empty data code stops and in output field post error text.
`Lot_Mean_r`, `Lot_SD_r`, `SSB_DF_r`, `SSW_DF_r`, `SST_DF_r` are input fields qdoubleSpinBox

```
if self.Lot_Mean_r<=0 or self.Lot_SD_r<=0 or self.SSB_DF_r<=0 or self.SSW_DF_r<=0 or self.SST_DF_r<=0 or float(item.text())<=0 or item==None:
            if self.Lot_Mean_r<=0: 
                self.ui.textEdit_status_N.append("Error: Lot Mean negative or less than 0")
            if self.Lot_SD_r<=0:         
                self.ui.textEdit_status_N.append("Error: Lot SD negative or less than 0")
            if self.SSB_DF_r<=0:         
                self.ui.textEdit_status_N.append("Error: SSB DF negative or less than 0")   
            if self.SSW_DF_r<=0:         
                self.ui.textEdit_status_N.append("Error: SSW DF negative or less than 0")  
            if self.SST_DF_r<=0:         
                self.ui.textEdit_status_N.append("Error: SST DF negative or less than 0")
            if item==None:
                self.ui.textEdit_status_N.append("Error: Input table has wrong data")
            elif float(item.text())<=0: self.ui.textEdit_status_N.append("Error: Input table has negative or 0 data")
else: [further calculations]
```

if I delete parts about cheking table cells, it works. In current state it not working if one of cells in table has zero\negative\empty data, it not printing error and further calculations goes, intstead of - error message about wrong data in table and stop further calculations. Single input fields works fine

Comment: @user19077881 checked what you say - it works not exactly as I want: it write only 1 error message when it should write at least 2. p.s. added part how it working now

Comment: Just iterate through the whole table using nested for loops: `for row in range(table.rowCount()):` `for column in range(table.columnCount()):` `item = table.item(row, column)`.